# Why does repaint(long) repaint immediately?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

According to the Javadoc, [JComponent.repaint(long)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28long%29) is supposed to schedule a repaint() sometime in the future. When I try using it it always triggers an immediate repaint. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Repaint
{
  public static final boolean works = false;

      private static class CustomComponent extends JPanel
  {
    private float alpha = 0;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setComposite(
        AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
      g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
      g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      alpha += 0.1;
      if (alpha > 1)
        alpha = 1;
      System.out.println("alpha=" + alpha);
      if (!works)
        repaint(1000);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new CustomComponent());
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    if (works)
    {
      new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
          frame.repaint();
        }
      }).start();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the Javadoc says the method will cause a repaint to happen *within* (not after) the specified time.

Comment: At the time this was written, Sun's JDK seems to ignore the "tm" parameter altogether. All concrete implementations propagate the argument to their container but no one ever uses it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to schedule something to be repainted, then you should be using a Swing Timer. You should not be scheduling painting from withing the paintComponnt(..) method. You can't control when the paintComponent() method is called.

Comment: Using a Timer is really the only way to go. If you try to schedule painting inside PaintComponent(), you run the risk of the component not repainting immediately if it is un-hidden when other components or programs are moved over it in a windowing environment.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter says tm - maximum time in milliseconds before update it does not say it won't do so immediately also the javadocs say

> Repaints the component. If this
>   component is a lightweight component,
>   this results in a call to paint 
>   within tm milliseconds.

Comment: JPanel is lightweight. Heavyweight components are those with peers (AWT Canvas, Panel, Window, Frame, Dialog, TextField, TextArea, List, Checkbox, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I am going to edit the answer hope thats ok

Answer (score 1):

If you search a little bit you find that this parameter is ignored in derived classes. ;)